# Ошибка запуска сервера PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-server, pgadmin4

Решил начать изучать PosgreSQL. Скачал с официального сайта Postgres и pgAdmin4. Но не могу запустить сервер в Postgres.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот логи:

```bash
2022-12-31 18:50:17.046 MSK [4727] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 15.1 on aarch64-apple-darwin21.6.0, compiled by Apple clang version 14.0.0 (clang-1400.0.29.102), 64-bit
2022-12-31 18:50:17.048 MSK [4727] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "127.0.0.1", port 5432
2022-12-31 18:50:17.048 MSK [4727] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::1", port 5432
2022-12-31 18:50:17.049 MSK [4727] FATAL:  could not open lock file "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432.lock": Permission denied
2022-12-31 18:50:17.050 MSK [4727] LOG:  database system is shut down
```

При этом если запустить сервер на другом порту всё работает. Но хотелось бы узнать почему я не могу запустить на 5432 порте.

Comment: Попробуй перезапустить саму службу postgres

Comment: @ИванПавлов А как это сделать?

Comment: ну как в линукс незнаю в винде через диспетчер задач можно называется postgresql-x64-{version}

Comment: @ИванПавлов Я перезагрузил не помогло. Я удалил программу и заново скачал, то же самое

Comment: возможно у вас уже запущен процесс. поэтому файл блокируется этим предыдущим. то есть занятся надо проверкой этой. еще резон удалить этот файл блокировки. он мог быть создан другим пользователем или административным доступом. который не может быть вам доступен.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FATAL:  could not open lock file "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432.lock": Permission denied

- уровень пользователя не позволяет управлять этим файлом
- новый запускаемый инстанс постгреса видит. что уже что-то работает на данном порту

1. ранее запущен процесс. который создал этот файл

- проверить и завершить все процессы

2. процесс ранее создан администратором, напр. root

- удалить этот файл. либо chown postgres:postgres`

Comment: также данный файл блокировки мог остаться неудалённым в результате аварийной остановки инстанса постгреса. можно просто удалить этот файл.

Comment: Спасибо! Уточню, что мне помогло удалить `/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432.lock` после чего я перезагрузил Mac и у меня запустился postgres процесс на порту 5432 (который не был запущен в PostgresApp). Через команду `sudo pkill -u postgres` я его остановил, и после этого я смог запустить сервер в PosgresApp

Comment: помогло, ставь плюсик  :) что совет полезен